# Can I enqueue a Queueable from inside of the Queueable class itself?

Tags: queueable-apex

I'm working on some code that needs to make callouts async (because it's run as part of a trigger) and am using `Queueable`. In my situation, there are some scenarios where the records are already in their target state and we need to prevent the Queueable class from being enqueued (to prevent an infinite loop).

The logic behind whether or not I should enqueue the job is fairly complex. The queueable class that I've created contains most of the raw data that I need to make the enqueue/don't enqueue determination.

It would be convenient (and possibly better design) if I could create a method in my Queueable class that can contain the enqueue logic and then equeue itself as appropriate.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can enqueue an instance of a Queueable from inside of the class itself.

The following example illustrates that this is possible because we have access to `this`, a reference to the particular instance of the class being used to call the method.

```java
public class ExperimentQueueable implements Queueable{
    public Boolean doEnqueue = false;
    
    public void enqueueSelf(){
        // insert complex logic here
        if(!doEnqueue){ return; }
        
        System.enqueueJob(this);
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext ctx){
        system.debug('run');
    }
}
```

The class is able to be saved, and then anonymous apex can be run to verify

```java
ExperimentQueueable eq = new ExperimentQueueable();
eq.enqueueSelf();
eq.doEnqueue = !eq.doEnqueue;
eq.enqueueSelf();
System.debug(Limits.getQueueableJobs()); // Prints "1", because the first call to enqueueSelf()
                                         //   returned before enqueuing
```

Comment: We use a method similar to this for queueable self-chaining, though to avoid getting an error on sandboxes if the self-chaining goes beyond a "depth" of 5, the method leverages a counter held in the queueable's state and when this exceeds max depth the queueable is chained via a future method (state must be put into a form that can be passed to a future, e.g. via JSON serialization).